# Need help Javascript validation input text and date

Tags: javascript

I want to be the valid input text of at least 8 characters and age greater than 16, and the exclusion of some of the icons using function in Javascript

Comment: the exclusion of some of the icons using function in Javascript ?

Comment: yes i need exclusion of some characters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validate() {
  //Make a selector pointing to your input first
  var myInput = document.getElementById('yourInputId').value

  //Validate length:
  if (myInput.length >= 8) {
  //Check for age 
  if (eval(myInput) >= 16) {
  alert('your input is ok!');

  }
  else {
  alert('Minimum age is 16!');
  }
  }
  else {
  alert('input too short!');
  }
}
```

P.S.: For *character exclusion* you should jump into **[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)**

(Tons of example on the web, just Google it!)

Comment: Note that the W3C is not the same as W3Schools -- the two [aren't related at all](http://www.w3fools.com/).